# How to customize bootstrap sidebar/sidenav?

Tags: html, css, web-applications, twitter-bootstrap

I need to make use of Twitter Bootstrap Sidebar for creating a menu in my web application.(Highlighted in red).
[image]

To create a menu as shown below. [image]

The top item has a dropdown as shown in mage. And Next items in menu should come below this.But this is what I get when I use the css.

[image]

Menu Item overlaping the other.

Here is the **bootstrap code:**

```
<div class="span3 bs-docs-sidebar">
    <ul class="nav nav-list bs-docs-sidenav affix">
      <li class="active"><a href="#dropdowns"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Dropdowns</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#buttonGroups"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Button groups</a></li>
      <li><a href="#buttonDropdowns"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Button dropdowns</a></li>
      <li><a href="#navs"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Navs</a></li>
      <li><a href="#navbar"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Navbar</a></li>
      <li><a href="#breadcrumbs"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Breadcrumbs</a></li>
      <li><a href="#pagination"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Pagination</a></li>
      <li><a href="#labels-badges"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Labels and badges</a></li>
      <li><a href="#typography"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Typography</a></li>
      <li><a href="#thumbnails"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Thumbnails</a></li>
      <li><a href="#alerts"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Alerts</a></li>
      <li><a href="#progress"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Progress bars</a></li>
      <li><a href="#media"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Media object</a></li>
      <li><a href="#misc"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Misc</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Here is **my code:**

```
 <div class="span3 bs-docs-sidebar">
    <ul class="nav nav-list bs-docs-sidenav affix">
        <li> <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                <i class="icon-user"></i>dany
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a id="logout" href="#">Sign Out</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="span3 bs-docs-sidebar">
    <ul class="nav nav-list bs-docs-sidenav `affix`">
        <li><a href="#approval" id="approval"></i>Approval Requests</a></li>
        <li><a href="#setting" id="setting"></i>Settings</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The css class in bootstrap setting the position is `bs-docs-sidenav` and `affix` I belive.
The css of docs.css of twitter bootstrap is [this](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/docs.css)

Anyone please help to solve this issue as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `span3` on both of your menus. That means the second menu will be placed on the next grid on the right, not below the first menu.

I believe you should start like this-

```
<div class="span3 bs-docs-sidebar">
    <ul class="nav nav-list bs-docs-sidenav affix">
        <li> <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                <i class="icon-user"></i>dany
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a id="logout" href="#">Sign Out</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="nav nav-list bs-docs-sidenav affix">
        <li><a href="#approval" id="approval"></i>Approval Requests</a></li>
        <li><a href="#setting" id="setting"></i>Settings</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now apply some CSS on the second menu e.g.

`<ul class="nav nav-list bs-docs-sidenav affix" style="top: 200px;">`

Answer (score 0):

You have created two div of span3 bs-docs-sidebar and hence you are seeing sidebars in parallel. If you want menu 'dany' fixed on the top, then its better to put them on top bar using `<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">`