# Twitter Bootstrap like vertical navigation bar on side

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap, and having a problem in creating navigation bar like bootstrap has.I invested lot of time trying it but unable to figure out.
What I want is like

[image]

This is what i found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14152378/how-to-customize-bootstrap-sidebar-sidenav)

```
<div class="span3 bs-docs-sidebar">
<ul class="nav nav-list bs-docs-sidenav affix">
  <li class="active"><a href="#dropdowns"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Dropdowns</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#buttonGroups"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Button groups</a></li>
  <li><a href="#buttonDropdowns"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Button dropdowns</a></li>
  <li><a href="#navs"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Navs</a></li>
  <li><a href="#navbar"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Navbar</a></li>
  <li><a href="#breadcrumbs"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Breadcrumbs</a></li>
  <li><a href="#pagination"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Pagination</a></li>
  <li><a href="#labels-badges"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Labels and badges</a></li>
  <li><a href="#typography"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Typography</a></li>
  <li><a href="#thumbnails"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Thumbnails</a></li>
  <li><a href="#alerts"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Alerts</a></li>
  <li><a href="#progress"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Progress bars</a></li>
  <li><a href="#media"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Media object</a></li>
  <li><a href="#misc"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Misc</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: what did u tried so far?

Comment: So what is not working? Do you want the menu to `affix` to the side like this: http://www.bootply.com/63708

Answer (score 11):

Copy the css of bs-sidebar from docs.css of twitter bootstrap;
add additional CSS that is separately defined at the bottom of the same file as below:

**CSS**

```css
.bs-sidebar .nav > .active > ul {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<div class="bs-sidebar affix">
    <ul class="nav bs-sidenav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">NAV1</a>
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">NAV2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer saved my day too. Now I just need to get it to color.

Answer (score 5):

Did u check bootstrap nav bar -> stackable section, [here](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#navs)?

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked">
  ...
</ul>
```

Looks like the same as you've asked... tried this?

Comment: Yeah i tried and it gives stacked tabs, but its not what i want

Comment: I want same as above snapshot(of bootstrap)

Comment: You've got the source of the page. Inspect what classes/styles they use apply in your code and you'll get the same result. They customized their nav with custom styles a bit...